# Camera Footprint on ground plane using Quaternion

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, .net, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am following this thread http://rijesha.com/2018/aerial-cam-footprint/

What I want to do is
**Plot drone camera footprint on basemap using information utmX,utmY,vFOV,hFOV,camera roll,camera
pitch,camera yaw,altitude**

Problem facing :

- Altitude working well
- Yaw and Roll working well (roll change : get trapezoid, yaw change : rotate around center)
- When I change Pitch value expected footprint shape is **trapezoid** (roll == 0). but I get is **rectangle**.

Algorithem flow looking like good as its just Quaternion rotation. Not sure about signs.
What could be the problem here?

**Code :** https://github.com/rijesha/CamFootprintTester/tree/master

[image: Working for Roll axis]

[image]

Comment: Seems like you need to have the lens focal length value and the sensor size as well https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

Comment: I have that information.  Calculated Fov from it.       
hfov = 2 * ( atan(currentCamera.sensW / (2 * currentCamera.focalLenght)));
vfov =  2 * atan(currentCamera.sensH / (2 * currentCamera.focalLenght));

hfov =  RadiansToDegrees(hfov);
vfov=  RadiansToDegrees(vfov);